# How to import 100 or more images in React js?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have created image folder in Src. But that is not working for Background-image:url('') in CSS file. Iam getting error. I have 100's of images. Every time i need to import and bind in jsx. Is there any other way to resolve this issue?

Comment: welcome to stcakoverflow.Can you share some code so that we can see  what have you tried and from there we can proceed

Comment: Image folder created in Src is working for all jsx page. But if there is a multiple images in a single file what to do? In some articles i came to know that we can create image folder in Public also. But that is not working in css BackgrounImage:url('')